# SwingWorker to change button in main gui class

Tags: java, class, swingworker

I have a Main GUI class with buttons and other controls.
When one of the buttons (let say btnGo) is selected it is disabled and a SwingWorker (currently part of a different class) is initiated to do something.

My wish is for the button to be enabled again when the SwingWorker finishes.

How do let my "child class" (for the lack of a better word) update a control in my main GUI class?

Answer (score 1):

Pass a reference to the button to your `SwingWorker` subclass's constructor. Then, in the `.done()` method, you can re-enable it.

The `.done()` method gets run on the GUI thread, so it can safely change the button state.

The alternative is to register the button as a `PropertyChangeListener` of the `SwingWorker`, so that it gets notified when the work is done.